# Emacs: Keybinding to TAB breaks autocompletion in minibuffer

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, minibuffer

Simply put, I just set a keybinding on the TAB key, but now when I push TAB in the minibuffer to auto-complete  a command, it fails with the following message: `The mark is not set now, so there is no region`.

In other words, I only need my TAB keybinding when my cursor is in the buffer (not the minibuffer).

In my example below, how can I set my tab to indent when I am in text/fundamental mode in the buffer without losing autocompletion while in the mini-buffer? I have the following functions and key-bindings:

```
;; Shift the selected region right if distance is postive, left if
;; negative

 (defun shift-region (distance)
   (let ((mark (mark)))
     (save-excursion
       (indent-rigidly (region-beginning) (region-end) distance)
       (push-mark mark t t)
       ;; Tell the command loop not to deactivate the mark
       ;; for transient mark mode
       (setq deactivate-mark nil))))

(defun shift-right ()
  (interactive)
  (shift-region 2))

(defun shift-left ()
  (interactive)
  (shift-region -2))

;; Bind (shift-right) and (shift-left) function to your favorite keys. I use
;; the following so that Ctrl-Shift-Right Arrow moves selected text one 
;; column to the right, Ctrl-Shift-Left Arrow moves selected text one
;; column to the left:

;; (global-set-key [C-S-right] 'shift-right)
;; (global-set-key [C-S-left] 'shift-left)
(global-set-key [tab] 'shift-right)
(global-set-key [backtab] 'shift-left)
```

Comment: I would select another key instead of `tab` for your `shift-right` -- `tab` is used by a lot of popular libraries and this is only the first of many problems yet to come (caused by taking global control over `tab`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is simply that you bound your command to `[tab]` rather than to `"\t"`.  `tab` denotes the TAB key under GUIs, but under a tty Emacs instead receives a TAB character (i.e. `?\t`), so when you hit `tab` Emacs first looks for a `tab` binding and if there isn't any, a `function-key-map` remapping turns it into a `?\t` and tries again.  The minibuffer only binds `"\t"`, so any global binding to `[tab]` will take precedence.

In short, use `(global-set-key "\t" 'shift-right)` and this problem will disappear.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what others have said:

1. The `TAB` key is typically *not* the same as `<tab>`, which is what you are using by specifying `[tab]`. The `TAB` key is the same as `C-i`, and you can use `(kbd "TAB")` to bind it.
2. You can, if you want to, go ahead and bind `TAB` to your command in the `global-map`, as you have done, but then override that for the minibuffer by rebinding it in each of the minibuffer keymaps to whatever commands you like for them.

   For example, if you want the usual minibuffer bindings for `TAB`, then do this:

   1. Start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file).
   2. Optionally load any library that makes a non-default minibuffer binding for `TAB` (e.g. autocomplete?).
   3. Load library [`help-fns+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/help-fns%2b.el), to obtain command `describe-keymap`, bound globally to `C-h M-k`.
   4. Use `C-h M-k` to check the binding of `TAB` in each of the minibuffer keymaps used by your version of Emacs.
      This will include `minibuffer-local-map`, `minibuffer-local-completion-map`, and `minibuffer-local-must-match-map`, and it may include some more.  See `(elisp) Completion Commands` for the list of minibuffer keymap variables.

      For example, `C-h M-k minibuffer-local-completion-map` shows you the bindings in that keymap. Look for `TAB` in the list.

      (If you don't want to download `help-fns+.el` then you can use `lookup-key`.  That library just makes listing the keys in a keymap easy.)
   5. Bind `TAB` to that default binding, in your init file, after having bound it globally to your non minibuffer-oriented command. IOW, restore the minibuffer bindings as they should be.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether you are in a minibuffer by using the function `window-minibuffer-p`. From the documentation

```
Return non-nil if WINDOW is a minibuffer window.
WINDOW must be a valid window and defaults to the selected one.
```

Also emacs 24.4 already provides the things you want to achieve in the functions above. The command `indent-rigidly` has been enhanced such that you can indent the regions using <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>shift-tab</kbd> keys.

You can select the region you want to indent and hit <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> after which you will be able to move the region by one space using the <kbd>right</kbd> and <kbd>left</kbd> keys. You can also move the selected region by one tab space using the <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>shift-tab</kbd> keys, it is really convenient since the keybindings above remain active until you press any other key.